# Broadcastreceiver and SMSReceiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

When I receive a message in my class SMSReceiver I want to play a sound start in the display activity. The problem is that each message receiving sound is played. But in the case I received 2 messages simultaneously blends the sounds.

Following is my code,

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals(SMSReceiver.SMS_RECEIVED)){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
        }
        String sms2 = new String();
        for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {
            if (TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), number)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, DisplayActivity.class);
                sms2 = msg.getMessageBody();
                i.putExtra("SMS",sms2);
                context.startActivity(i);
                abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
    }
}
}


public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

MessageBDD messagebdd = new MessageBDD(this);
Message message = new Message();

int delay = 0;
boolean isFirstTime = true;
int period = 60000;
static String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);


    final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.son1);

     AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {
              if (isFirstTime) {
               isFirstTime = false;
               mPlayer.start();
              }
              else{
                  mPlayer.seekTo(0);
                  mPlayer.start();
              }
          }
          }, delay, period);

    /*************Sauvegarde des messages*****************************/
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String sms = extra.getString("SMS");
    messagebdd.Open();
    message.setContenu(sms);
    messagebdd.insertMessage(message);
    messagebdd.Close();


    /******************Alerte de stop sonnerie**********************/
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Message");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Stopper la notification?");

    alertDialog.setButton("STOP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        mPlayer.release();
        finish();
    }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
}



public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String number = "15555215556";
int delay = 0;
boolean isFirstTime = true;
int period = 60000;
final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.son1);

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          String action = intent.getAction();
          if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
             AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

                        mPlayer.start();

          }
       }
    };

    @Override
       public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
       }

     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
           super.onStart(intent, startId);

       }

    public void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           unregisterReceiver(receiver);
       }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: /your question is not clear. what is happening and what do u want??

Comment: @Andrey: please check the last ring time and accordingly add the conditions whether the upcoming should be rang.

Comment: ok I'll edit. just 1 minutes

Comment: put your ring play code in service and run service when receive any message. In case two messages check if service is running then don't start service.

Comment: ok i'll try it. don't leave me

Comment: I try with a service that starts when the phone is on. 
But the service does not seem to work. I just update the code

Comment: thank you for your intervention. what I do before I had a broadcast class that starts the display activity class which included the song. But the problem is that each reception of sms a new instance starts and I do not know exactly when checking the current Mediaplayer

Answer (score 1):

Make all MediaPlayer work in another singleton class and call a method play which will play the music. and check if mediaPlayer.isPlaying() is true then don't play the music.
I hope it will help.

Comment: thank you for your intervention. what I do before I had a broadcast class that starts the display activity class which included the song. But the problem is that each reception of sms a new instance starts and I do not know exactly when checking the current Mediaplayer

Comment: Yes I am getting your point.Each reception will open new Activity so you have to make a class say AudioHelper which will be singleton and do all the work loading- unloading of media player and playing of music...so when activity is again started you will get same object as it is singleton and you can check isPlaying()

Comment: thank you. I just do it with a service. look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239419/stop-all-media-player-rinning-in-my-android-device. please. thank