# Stop all media player rinning in my android device

Tags: android, media-player

I'll like to stopping all media player in my android device programmatically.
Someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Service` to play `MediaPlayer` and control from anywhere in application.
I used this tutorial and I succeeded.
https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services